# OSXで、telnetで外部機器に接続、外部機器の制御コマンドを実行するには

Tags: macos, sh

OSXで、telnetで外部機器に接続、外部機器の制御コマンドを実行する方法についての質問です。

下記のように書いてみましたが、うまく動きませんので、どう修正すればよいでしょうか。
なお、外部機器のログインにはユーザネームとパスワードは不要にしています。

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sh /Users/hoge/Desktop/cmds.sh | telnet 192.168.1.2 5024 >> auto-telnet.log
```

cmds.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 30; echo command
sleep 5; echo exit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

よくある簡単なタスクなので[`expect`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/201) コマンドで sleep しながらでもいいでしょう。

以下、順に例を挙げます。

#### 練習: bash を立ち上げ `echo`

echo_in_bash.sh:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Bash を起動
spawn bash
# プロンプト "$" を待ってコマンドを打つ
expect "$" { send "echo Hello World\r"; }
expect "$" { send "exit\r"; }
# 終了
interact
```

#### 練習: Google に telnet して ページを取得

get_google_html.sh:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 20
set address "www.google.com"
set port "80"

# Telnet で接続
spawn telnet $address $port
# 一秒待つ
sleep 1
# ドキュメントを要求
send "GET /\r\r";
# 終了
expect eof
```

#### 実践: 質問にあわせたスクリプトの例

質問の要件では、以下のような感じになるでしょう。待ちプロンプト等は環境に合わせてください。

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 20
set address "my_machine_ip"
set port "23"

spawn telnet $address $port
expect "$" { sleep 30; send "command\r"; }
expect "$" { sleep 5; send "exit\r"; }
expect eof
```

Comment: 無事、動作することができました。
段階を追って説明いただいたので、よく理解できました。
どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

GNU NetCat (nc)を使うと便利です。

```
sh /Users/hoge/Desktop/cmds.sh | nc 192.168.1.2 5024 >> auto-telnet.log
```